# How to implement the same function use *Layer function?

Tags: customization, neural-networks

Reading [YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) method to detect object in the image([paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf)),I want to train this tiny-VOLO v1 on `Mathematica`,but the special loss function is very difficult to write.

Total loss is:

[image]

For brief,I use 1-dim vec to make a example.

This is ordinary MSE function,but it does't have `Mask` like the loss in the image.

```
MeanSquaredLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
 "Target" -> {3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2}|>](*4.16667*)
```

So I define a function:

```
meanSquareLoss = Mean[#Mask*(#Input - #Target)^2] &;
N@meanSquareLoss[<|"Mask" -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 "Input" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
 "Target" -> {3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2}|>](*4.16667*)

N@meanSquareLoss[<|"Mask" -> {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 
 "Input" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
 "Target" -> {3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2}|>](*3.33333*)

net = NetGraph[{ThreadingLayer[(#1 - #2)^2 &], 
    ThreadingLayer[Times]}, {{NetPort["Input"], NetPort["Target"]} -> 1 -> 2,
    NetPort["Mask"] -> 2}]
Mean@net[<|"Input" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
  "Target" -> {3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2}, 
  "Mask" -> {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}|>](*3.33333*)
(*Because mma don't have MeanLayer[]*)
```

This way to define a loss net it throws error:

```
NetGraph[{ThreadingLayer[(#1 - #2)^2 &], 
     ThreadingLayer[Times], TotalLayer[]}, {{NetPort["Input"], 
     NetPort["Target"]} -> 1 -> 2, NetPort["Mask"] -> 2 -> 3}]
```

> NetGraph::tyinc: Value for "Input" port of layer 3 (a list of tensors) is inconsistent with value for "Output" port of layer 2 (a tensor).

But Using the `TotalLayer[]` is just want to calculate the sum of all the elements...

And I want to use `ConstantArrayLayer`.

```
MeanSquaredLossMaskLayer = NetGraph[{ThreadingLayer[(#1 - #2)^2 &],ThreadingLayer[Times], 
   ConstantArrayLayer[], MeanSquaredLossLayer[]}, 
   {{NetPort["Input"], NetPort["Target"]} -> 1 -> 2 -> NetPort[4, "Input"], 
   3 -> NetPort[4, "Target"], NetPort["Mask"] -> 2}]
```

But it can not use `NetInitialize@MeanSquaredLossMaskLayer`...

So how to define a custom loss function like this using `*Layer` funtion?
if use 2-dims or higer dimension? How to add `Mask` into it?

And I find it has no `*Layer` function can do `Map[Max, #, {2}]&` that not only reduce the dimension of input but also use the `Max` to spicific dimension.

I try the `NetMapOperator[ElementwiseLayer[Max], "Input" -> {20, 7, 7}]`,but the dimension of output is also `{20, 7, 7}`.

By the way `PartLayer` is not support `{All,1}`...

So how to write the custom loss function more effectly?

[image]

Comment: `NetChain[{AggregationLayer[Max]}, "Input" -> {20, 7, 7}]`

Comment: `meanLayer = {ReplicateLayer[1], AggregationLayer[Mean], PartLayer[1]}`

Comment: Replace `TotalLayer` with `SummationLayer`.